# How to convert a list of strings with key/values into a dictionary

Tags: python, list

I have a list which is given below.I have extracted this list from a text file by searching for these particular fields.Now i want to remove the unwanted words(tyrone cluster,resources_used etc) and write it into a new file .The list size changes every time but the fields remain the same

job_list:

```
['Job Id: 49361.tyrone-cluster', 'resources_used.cput = 14:32:14', 'resources_used.mem = 13955852kb', 'resources_used.vmem = 14199016kb', 'resources_used.walltime = 05:23:02', 'job_state = R', 'queue = qp32', 'Job Id: 49362.tyrone-cluster', 'job_state = Q', 'queue = batch', 'comment = Not Running: Queue not an execution queue.', 'Job Id: 49395.tyrone-cluster', 'resources_used.cput = 31:20:32', 'resources_used.mem = 19179712kb', 'resources_used.vmem = 158305072kb', 'resources_used.walltime = 01:57:34', 'job_state = R', 'queue = idqueue', 'Job Id: 49396.tyrone-cluster', 'resources_used.cput = 46:26:45', 'resources_used.mem = 5347092kb', 'resources_used.vmem = 7588024kb', 'resources_used.walltime = 01:44:50', 'job_state = R', 'queue = qp32', 'Job Id: 49408.tyrone-cluster', 'job_state = Q', 'queue = qp32']
```

the output of the new file should be

job.txt

```
49361 14:32:14 13955852kb 14199016kb 05:23:02 R qp32
49362 Q batch
49395 31:20:32 19179712kb 158305072kb 01:57:34 R idqueue
49396 46:26:45 5347092kb  7588024kb 01:44:50 R qp32
49408 Q qp32
```

Comment: What do you mean by unwanted words?

Comment: If you want a regex to extract only numerical expressions with units times, etc. Then what have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: data=the list
key_value_pairs=[item.split("=") for item in data]
my_dict={}
for item in key_value_pairs:
    if len(item)==2:
        my_dict[item[0]]=item[1]
        
print(my_dict.keys(),my_dict.values())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is a bit different, first finding the job elements of the list, then handling each "block" at a time.

Each job block's information is compiled in the `row` list, which is then appended to `rows` list when the job block has ended.

```
import re

l = ['Job Id: 49361.tyrone-cluster', 'resources_used.cput = 14:32:14', 'resources_used.mem = 13955852kb', 'resources_used.vmem = 14199016kb', 'resources_used.walltime = 05:23:02', 'job_state = R', 'queue = qp32', 'Job Id: 49362.tyrone-cluster', 'job_state = Q', 'queue = batch', 'comment = Not Running: Queue not an execution queue.', 'Job Id: 49395.tyrone-cluster', 'resources_used.cput = 31:20:32', 'resources_used.mem = 19179712kb', 'resources_used.vmem = 158305072kb', 'resources_used.walltime = 01:57:34', 'job_state = R', 'queue = idqueue', 'Job Id: 49396.tyrone-cluster', 'resources_used.cput = 46:26:45', 'resources_used.mem = 5347092kb', 'resources_used.vmem = 7588024kb', 'resources_used.walltime = 01:44:50', 'job_state = R', 'queue = qp32', 'Job Id: 49408.tyrone-cluster', 'job_state = Q', 'queue = qp32']

job_elements = [i for (i,e) in enumerate(l) if re.match(r'Job Id: (\d+)', e)] + [len(l) + 1]

rows = []
for (s,e) in zip(job_elements[:-1], job_elements[1:]):
    row = []
    for line in l[s:e]:
        mat = re.match(r'Job Id: (\d+)', line)
        if mat:
            row.append(mat.group(1).strip())
            continue
        mat = re.match(r'.* = (.*)', line)
        if mat:
            row.append(mat.group(1).strip())
            continue

    rows.append(' '.join(row))

# Print output :
for r in rows:
    print r

# Or write to file:
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for r in rows:
        f.write(r)        # You could write these two lines as f.write(r + '\n')
        f.write('\n')     #   if you didn't care about creating a string unnecessarily
```

Outputs:

```
49361 14:32:14 13955852kb 14199016kb 05:23:02 R qp32
49362 Q batch Not Running: Queue not an execution queue.
49395 31:20:32 19179712kb 158305072kb 01:57:34 R idqueue
49396 46:26:45 5347092kb 7588024kb 01:44:50 R qp32
49408 Q qp32
```

For reference, `(s,e) in zip(job_elements[:-1], job_elements[1:])` produces the following tuples, which are the starting (inclusive) and ending (exclusive) indices of the "Job Id" entries of the original list:

```
( 0,  7)
( 7, 11)
(11, 18)
(18, 25)
(25, 29)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [6]: for s in ss:
    m = re.match('Job Id: (\d+)',s)
    if m:
        sys.stdout.write('\n'+m.group(1)+' ')
        continue
    m = re.match('^.+ = (.+)$',s)
    if m:
       sys.stdout.write(m.group(1)+' ')
       continue
   ...:  

49361 14:32:14 13955852kb 14199016kb 05:23:02 R qp32 
49362 Q batch Not Running: Queue not an execution queue. 
49395 31:20:32 19179712kb 158305072kb 01:57:34 R idqueue 
49396 46:26:45 5347092kb 7588024kb 01:44:50 R qp32 
49408 Q qp32
```